# Answer to duplicate question no longer relevant once merged

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer

I answered [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/send-messages-between-computers-over-network) yesterday regarding a local network chat application, my answer was valid, well received, and accepted.

Sometime overnight the question was closed as a duplicate of [Cross-platform LAN messenger](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/cross-platform-lan-messenger/13712), which is perfectly fine - the two questions had very similar goals, and if I'd known about the older question I would have flagged it myself.

My issue is that in migrating my answer to the older question my answer is the exact piece of software that the older question calls out as unacceptable (unless I could provide a workaround for the issue that makes it unacceptable, which I can't).

So now my answer has gone from being a good answer to a terrible answer.

In this situation what should I do?

- Leave my answer as-is and expect downvotes (I would downvote an answer that obviously ignores something stated in the question, so I'm sure others would too)?
- Edit my answer to add a proviso stating that it was an answer to a duplicate question which did not single out this piece of software as unacceptable (and still expect downvotes)?
- Delete my answer, removing a perfectly valid software recommendation that just doesn't quite fit the question it is on, and thus never have this software recommended here because practically every question that could be asked to which this software is the answer will be closed as a duplicate of the question to which this answer is not acceptable?
- Any other ideas?

Comment: My mistake. I thought I had all the boxes checked, looks like I didn't. Apologies. I'm going to see what can be done about this from my side (likely not much), but if I were you I'd edit to add a proviso and explain the situation. I wouldn't expect many downvotes, and your answer will still be helpful for many (majority) of cases. Again, apologies.

Comment: My bad also because I was the one who suggested the merge. I didn't realize the question specifically called your software out. To avoid such a confusion in the future it might be a good idea to edit the "master" question slightly to make that a more obvious and concrete requirement so it won't get accidentally overlooked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This was completely my fault, I should have seen that. A community manager has unmerged it. Thanks for reporting it!

And I'll be a whole lot more careful in the future. Much like Santa, checking lists *twice*.

Comment: No worries, easily done. The master question named it as "Qualia LAN Messenger" (company name plus app name) while I just called the program by its name, so there is space for confusion. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: You have my undying respect because of your willingness to admit and reverse your mistake. Would that we have more like you.